# CORS error on POST, PUT, & DELETE request, but GET working fine

Tags: rest, express, http-headers, cors

I'm currently building an application using MERN stack and I'm having problems accessing my REST api. It's able to fetch data using get request, but writing data seems to fail.

I have this code block before declaring my routes:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://staging.domain.io');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
```

I'm using axios in the front end to make those api calls and have withCredentials attribute set to true

### Some things to note that might be of use:

I'm sharing my cookies within my domains and subdomains by using cookie-session (declared BEFORE CORS configuration (above code)

```
app.use(
  session({
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys: [process.env.SESSION_ENCRYPTION],
    domain: 'domain.io',
    signed: true,
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false
  }));
```

This only failed when I deployed to GCP, it was working fine on localhost.

### What I've tried so far:

Used express cors middleware package and configured it as follows:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: 'https://staging.domain.io/',
    credentials: true
  })
);
app.options(
  "*",
  cors({
    origin: 'https://staging.domain.io/',
    credentials: true
  })
);
```

Seems like this code is not changing the behavior at all since there was nothing different regardless if that code is placed. However, if I keep that code and remove the code at the very top, the whole api fails (even GET requests).

So now I'm kinda stuck as to how to go about this problem. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the exact error messages that the browser is logging in the devtools console?

Comment: @sideshowbarker I'm getting this error (removed api request route): "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://stagingapi.domain.io/...' from origin 'https://staging.domain.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."

Comment: The error message in your comment indicates the server’s not responding to the CORS preflight with 200 OK but instead with some HTTP error code. You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to see exactly what HTTP error code it’s responding with. You can also check the server logs on API server you’re sending the request to, and see what messages the server is logging there before it responds with what HTTP error it’s sending back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days and a lot of head scratches, I've figured out where I've gone wrong. For the cors package approach, the origin attribute is not equal to the request's header origin

Request Header:

- Origin: staging.domain.io

and cors's origin attribute is

- origin: staging.domain.io/

All I had to do was remove the slash from the origin in cors, haha.

First approach (without the use of cors) issue still remains though.